# How check if ajax.googleapis.com blocked and use my hosting of jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
but some compaty may block this site, so in this case I want to use my local version on jquery
/JavaScripts/jquery.min.js.
How can I do it?

Comment: No company in their right mind will block `ajax.googleapis.com`.

Comment: I guess he means a router that might block all outgoing requests

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to work with all kind of mind companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(typeof(jQuery) === 'undefined'){             
    var scr =   document.createElement('script');
                scr.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
                scr.setAttribute('src', 'http://yourdomain/jquery.min.js');

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scr);
    setTimeout(function(){
        // $(document).ready(); here for instance
    }, 3000);
```